# Google Cloud - How to determine Key ID from P12?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

From [https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?project=[id]](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?project=%5Bid%5D), a user with the right permissions can provision a service account key. Nowadays, they hand it to you in JSON format, but they used to give you the option to receive a P12 (of which the JSON is just the P12 base64'd, with metadata). I have inherited an older project to maintain, and I have a P12 to authenticate with.

However, there are multiple key IDs listed for the given service account. I'd like to rotate them all out and delete everything except for a newly provisioned key. I can't create a new one, because the max is already reached (10). But I can't delete at random, because the application still needs to run unhindered. Only one is needed, and short of roulette, I can't figure out a way to determine WHICH key I have.

I am able to authenticate:

```
[~/scratch]$ gcloud auth activate-service-account x@developer.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=x.p12 --prompt-for-password
Password:
WARNING: .p12 service account keys are not recomended unless it is necessary for backwards compatability. Please switch to a newer .json service account key for this account.
Activated service account credentials for: [x@developer.gserviceaccount.com]
```

and then run commands. But I can't find a way, either through Gcloud, or trickery, to get Google to tell me WHICH key I have. I've tried a bunch of gcloud commands. Is there anything in GCP logging, straight API calls, undocumented commands, or something obvious I've missed?

Comment: There's no way you can determine the ID from the key itself (regardless it being Json or p12).

You have to dig into you apps and check which is using which key - it's a tedious task but there's no other way. 

But you may also try [Google Support](https://cloud.google.com/support#tab2) to get a proper help - I can't tell though it's feasible what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key ID is the SHA1 fingerprint of the accompanying certificate. You can extract the SHA1 fingerprint from the pkcs12 file with the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in /your/pkcs12/file.p12 -nodes | openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint
```

Comment: Incredible! That was it!